# The Smooth Scrolling is not working next/link

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, anchor, next-link

I am using next/Link but smooth scrolling is not working but when i use anchor tag it is working properly while using anchor tag page is reloading but next/link doesnt load page whenever path changes

`Css`

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

`index.js`

```
{
navItems.map((item, index) => (
    <Link key={index} href={item.href} passHref legacyBehavior>
          <a className="w-full px-4 py-4 -ml-4 text-gray-500 rounded-md dark:text-gray-300 hover:text-gradient focus:text-gradient focus:bg-indigo-100 dark:focus:bg-gray-800 focus:outline-none dark:focus:bg-neutral-700"
              aria-label="Toggle Menu"
              onClick={handleOpen}
           >
              {item.name}
           </a>
     </Link>
))}
```

Need smooth scrolling with next/link

Comment: Please don't put a link inside a link, it's semantically incorrect. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#technical_summary): *"Permitted content: no descendant may be interactive content or an `a` element"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue you have to add `!important` in the CSS and it will fix the issue.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}
```